# Function and Relations

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics, relations

I have a small question, if anyone could shed some light I would be really grateful!

we have this relation R: ∀ x,y ∈ "≈" , [(x≈y) ⇔ (| x - y| ≤ 0.5)]

Also relation R belongs to real numbers ℝ.

Is it reflective, symmetric , transitive or anti-symmetric ?

I done some research on Wikipedia and read about these terms and saw the visuals too.

i suppose that x=4.5 and y=5 then:

I think it is both reflective and symmetric.

I also think that it cant be transitive though (say there is a C=5.5, then y≈c but not x≈c) . I have no idea if it is anti-symmetric! This answer came intuitively , but i don't know how can i express this in a formal way!

Any advises are welcome ;)

Comment: Reflexive: $x\backsim x, \forall x \in \Bbb R$. Is $|x-x|\le 0.5$? Symmetric: If $x\backsim y$ then $y\backsim x$. So if $|x-y|\le 0.5$ then is it also true that $|y-x|\le 0.5$? Transitive: If $x\backsim y$ and $y\backsim z$ then $x\backsim z$. So if $|x-y|\le 0.5$ and $|y-z|\le 0.5$ then is it true that $|x-z|\le 0.5$?

Comment: That's not true, @andraiamatrix: the equality relation is both symmetric and antisymmetric.

Comment: Woops sorry. I'll delete that part of the comment

Comment: Hmmm...are you sure, @amWhy ? I mean, whenever transitivity, reflexivity and/or symmetry are fulfilled then by definition the relation isn't anti....whatever?

Comment: @Don Antisymmetry doesn't mean not symmetric. The relation $R = \{(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4)\}$ on the set $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ is an equivalence relation, hence is symmetric. It is also antisymmetric.

Comment: That I understand, @amWhy. Over here, "non-symmetry" is denote a-symmetry . I am asking about *definitions*.

Comment: The relation I give above is *trivially* antisymmetric. $$\forall x, y \in S, [((x, y) \in R \land (y, x) \in R ) \implies x = y]$$

Comment: @amWhy is my relation (OP) anti-symmetric then? I am confused. I think going by definition this particular is not Anti-symmetric " if R(a,b) and R(b,a), then a = b" . It is not antisymmetric because in fact a≈b and not a=b.

Comment: @Jake You're right, your relation is NOT antisymmetric. The one I posted in the comment above IS antisymmetric. I didn't mean to confuse!

Comment: alright thanks mate.

Comment: The answer tells us that approximate equality is not an equivalence relation. This is the fact that makes real analysis what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints: you have to find out whether

$$\text{Reflexivity}:\forall\,x,y\in\Bbb R\;,\;\;|x-x|\le\frac12\;\;?$$

$$\text{Symmetry}:\forall\,x,y\in\Bbb R\;,\;\;|x-y|\le\frac12\implies |y-x|\le\frac12\;\;?$$

$$\text{Transitivity}:\forall\,x,y,z\in\Bbb R\;,\;\left(|x-y|\le\frac12\;\wedge\;|y-z|\le\frac12\right)\implies |x-z|\le\frac12\;\;?$$

Funrther hint: work a *little* harder on the third one above...

Comment: hey thanks. Do i have to pick some real numbers in order to show this? Or a theoretical answer is enough? I mean in transitivity, i understand what you are writing, but shouldn't i use real numbers as a counter example? (i think it is obvious that this relation isn't transitive).

Comment: You have to develop *a feeling* for it: if you think something's false you need one single counter example, but if you think something's true then you *must* prove it in general. For example (further hint), the first two above are true, whereas the third one's false...and, of course, you have to use elements from the set you're working with, in this case, apparently, the real numbers.

Answer (score 3):

**Reflexive:**

- $\forall x \in \mathbb R, \; |x - x| = 0 \leq 0.5.$ 
   Therefore, the relation is reflexive.

**Symmetric:**

- $\forall x, y \in \mathbb R,\;\text{if }\; |x - y| \leq 0.5 \iff |y -
     x| \leq 0.5$. Hence, $x\approx y \iff y\approx z$. 
   Therefore, the relation is symmetric.

**Transitive:**

- For transitivity, we need for the following to be true:

  $$\forall\,x,y,z \in \mathbb R,\;\text{ if } \; \Big(|x-y|\leq
     0.5\;\land\; |y-z|\leq 0.5\Big), \;\text{ then }\; |x-z|\leq 0.5$$ You've provided a nice counterexample: $x = 4.5, y = 5,\; \text{and} \; z = 5.5$. Then we have $x \approx y$ and $y \approx z$, but NOT $x \approx z$.

So the relation is reflexive, symmetric, but not transitive.

**Note:**

To prove that a relation *has a property*, you need to show that for *arbitrary* elements in your set (**not** specific numbers), the relation holds. That is, we use arbitrary elements (which represent any element in the set) because if a property holds for these arbitrary elements, it holds for all elements.

To prove that a relation does **not** satisfy a property, it is enough to find and explicitly provide a counterexample: any specific values in the set that shows that the property fails *for all* elements in the set, thereby proving that the relation does not have that property.

Comment: Needs another TU +++1